# ingresar parametro abstracto en interfaces

Tags: java, android-studio

buenas noches, tengo una duda ¿cómo agrego como parametro una clase abstracta en un método hecho en una interface? esto con el fin que al llamar implementar la interface pueda agregar cualquier tipo de clase abstracta. Mi interface es esta

```
public interface DBM {

String STRING_TYPE = "text";
String INT_TYPE = "integer";
String BOOLEAN_TYPE = "boolean";
String FLOAT_TYPE = "float";
String POINT_TYPE = "point";

String TABLA_BAR="bar";
String CAMPO_ID_BAR="id_bar";
String CAMPO_NOMBRE_BAR="nom_bar";
String CAMPO_CALIFICACION_BAR="cal_bar";

String CREAR_BAR="CREATE TABLE "+TABLA_BAR+"" +
        "("+CAMPO_ID_BAR+" "+INT_TYPE+" "+CAMPO_NOMBRE_BAR+" " +
        ""+STRING_TYPE+" "+CAMPO_CALIFICACION_BAR+" "+FLOAT_TYPE+")";
String ELIMINAR_BAR="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLA_BAR;


boolean add(**aquí quiero ingresar la clase abstracta**);
boolean delete(**aquí quiero ingresar la clase abstracta**);
boolean update(**aquí quiero ingresar la clase abstracta**);
ArrayList getAll(**aquí quiero ingresar la clase abstracta**);
```

}

y cuando la implemente pueda usar una clase por ejemplo

`boolean add(Clientes cliente){
     return true;
 }`

Comment: Hola @Matthew Seidel, no tengo muy claro qué quieres hacer con la clase que dices... Quieres que sea del mismo tipo que la clase que la implementa? O quieres que sirva para *marcar* el tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución más elegante sería, usando Generics:

```
public interface DBM<T extends Object> {
...
   boolean add(T objeto);
   boolean delete(T objeto);
   boolean update(T objeto);
   List<T> getAll(T objeto);
}
```

Y para implementarla:

```
  public class ClienteDBM implements DBM<Cliente> {
           public boolean add(Cliente objeto){
               ....
           }

           public boolean delete(Cliente cliente)
               ....
           }
           public boolean update(Cliente cliente)
               ....
           }
           public List<Cliente> getAll(Cliente cliente)
               ....
           }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, creo que `T extends Object` se puede dejar por `T`. Y si ya lo quieres dejar totalmente flexible, no imponer que se acepte `Cliente`, sino `? extends Cliente`.

Comment: Era un ejemplo, debería ajustarlo a su caso de negocio concreto. Object me parece un ámbito demasiado amplio.

Answer (score 0):

encontré una solución momentanea

```
boolean add(Object [] objeto);
```

al invocar la función se debe ingresar todos los valores de la clase abstracta como objeto y por último, se ingresa en la función este objeto